# How to proxy particular host using http-proxy-middleware?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, proxy

I am using http-proxy-middleware to proxy hosts in my React project.

Below is the code from **setupProxy.js** file:

```
const {createProxyMiddleware} = require('http-proxy-middleware');

module.exports = function(app) {
  app.use('/api', createProxyMiddleware({ target: 'http://localhost:8080', changeOrigin: true, }));
  app.use('/api/user/logout', createProxyMiddleware({ target: 'http://localhost:9091', changeOrigin: true, }))
};
```

As you can see I added two proxy codes. For the logout, I want to use a different host. `/api` is working fine, but the `/api/user/logout` is not working.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Because when the request goes to '/api/user/logout'.
app.use('/api') finds '/api' in the url and it fits the condition of the first app.use

You need to use regExp

```
app.use(/\/api\/?$/, createProxyMiddleware())
```

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/exciting-alex-e8rg8?file=/src/index.js